# Google App Engine authenticate Google Cloud PHP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am integrating my PHP Laravel app to use the Google Cloud Logging API. I need to specify the service account json file in the code.

When running the app on App Engine where shall I place the service account json file such that it doesn't get submitted to git?

Thanks

Comment: For Google compute services such as App Engine, Cloud Run, etc. you do not need to use a service account JSON key file. Instead, use the credentials in metadata. The Google SDK and libraries have this support built in. Since you have not posted your code, research Appliication Default Credentials for App Engine.

Comment: Hey John, I found your article and it’s really helpful! Thanks